# Confusion about the Bellman Equation

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, dynamic-programming

In some resources, the belman equation is shown as below:

$v_{\pi}(s) = \sum\limits_{a}\pi(a|s)\sum\limits_{s',r}p(s',r|s,a)\big[r+\gamma v_{\pi}(s')\big] $

The thing that I confused is that, the $\pi$  and $p$ parts at the right hand side.

Since the probability  part -  $p(s',r|s,a)$- means that the probability of being at next state ($s'$), and since being at next state ($s'$) has to be done via following a specific action, the $p$ part also includes the probability of taking the specific actions inside it.

But then, why the $\pi(a|s)$ is written at the beginning of the equation? Why do we need it? Isn't the possibility of taking an action stated at the $p(s',r|s,a)$ part already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$p(s', r | s, a)$ is the probability of arriving at state $s'$ and obtain reward $r$  given that the environment was in state $s$ and the agent took action $a$. Therefore, this probability is defined **assuming action $a$ is taken**. There is no probability of taking $a$ included there.

The probability of the agent taking an action is provided by the policy $\pi$, and that is why we need it in the equation.

You can think of the interaction of these two terms with the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability): $p(A)=\sum _{n}p(A\mid B_{n})p(B_{n})$, where $p(B_{n})$ is analogous to $\pi(a|s)$ and $p(A\mid B_{n})$ is analogous to $p(s', r | s, a)$.

Comment: So, Are you suggesting that even if an action was selected under a **probabilistic criteria** which was represented by **π**, there is still a room for a different action? Why is that? Some sort of shock?

Comment: An action **can** be selected with a specific probability, defined by $\pi$. The $\sum_a$ adds over all possible actions.

Comment: Well, sorry for making you bore. One more thing. I understand $\sum_a$  part. However, what I understand from your words is, you suggest that, even if an action is selected  since it is more likely to be taken (say action $a_1$  which brings us to $s'$), it does not mean that we will reach the $s'$ for sure. There is still a probability to move some other state say $s''$ which has to be reached by taking another action say action $a_2$  which we haven't desired to select?

Comment: No. The value function (what you posted), estimates the value of some state $s$ by computing the rewards obtained reaching to all possible states $s'$ by all possible actions $a$. The value function does not deal with "selecting an action", just with the probability of doing so, the probability of reaching a state by taking an action, and the reward to be obtained doing so (and, recursively, the value of this new state).

Comment: One thing that may not be clear to OP is that the sums are *nested*, which is how $a$ gets to be defined in the second sum. This is a standard notation for nested sums, but if the OP's background is more engineering than maths, it might be less familiar